# Unable to vlookup from a comma seperated array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Hello I am struggling hard with a vlookup function,

I want to look up Designator(B) in GEMS BOM Designator(F), but the problem is column F is comma seperated values. As far as i know, its impossible to solve this problem. could you please help from the image below?

[image: excel image]

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($F$2:$F$100)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&B2&",",","&$F$2:$F$100&","))),1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below approach to get output.

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(B2&",",$F$2:$F$100&",",1),$G$2:$G$100)`

Make sure to adjust the range references and return references to suit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the use of database functions in Excel is more efficient than the use of array formulas and it's a very powerful, versatile and generic tool.

1. Suppose the table title is on line 1. My Excel is from Office 365.
2. Remove the spaces from the column headings (Line 1), as required in the database functions.
3. Name column `B` (Ctrl + F3), for example, `C_COD`.
4. Open a new column `H` before the current column `H` (which will be changed to `I`) and put `CRIT` in cell `H1` or any other title
5. In the new `CRIT` column put the formula
   `=NOT(ISERR (SEARCH(C_Cod, GemsBomDesignator)))` IN `H2` and copy until the end of the table. Don't worry about the error value in the evaluation
6. In cell `E2` put the formula `=DGET($F$2:$G$1000,"Value", H1:H2)` and copy it down.

Replace `1000` with the number of the bottom row of your table.

**Explanation**:

`DGET` is a database function in EXCEL for extract a value. The  first parameter is a "database" table, a simple and dense table with column names (without spaces) in the first line. "Value" is the name of the "field" to return, which is the title of the desired column in double quotes, and `H1:H2` is the criteria (condition), where `H2` is the condition of the criteria and `H1` just the previous line with any content (there is no logic in it, in this case, but it is a function requirement).

The criteria can be an expression with two special observations:

**a)** a column name is used (in this case, `C_COD`), to access a value outside the table (prefix @ to indicate the use of a single value). This value is always extracted along the same line as the criteria. It's a trick to put the criteria once and just copy it down with no changes.

**b)** Any value of the table can be referenced merely by using the name of a column in double quotes. It's more readable.